# C++ Segfault when using types from a shared library in a global variable destructor

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

I've come across an issue where the destructor of a global variable, which relies on instances of classes from a shared library, causes a segmentation fault at the conclusion of the program.

Unfortunately this comes from a rather large code base, and a minimal working example doesn't exhibit the problem, so I can't provide specific code here.

A class that looks something like this is causing the segfault:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo()
    {
        //...
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        Bar mybar; //Bar is an object defined in the shared library.
    }
};
```

when used in a program that is something like:

```
Foo myfoo;

int main()
{
    /* Code */
    return(0);
}
```

Why does this occur? If my type is declared in a local scope, no error occurs when it goes out of scope and the destructor is called at that point - the error only happens with a global variable.

I've done a bit of research and I'm wondering if the problem has something to do with the shared library of which `Bar` is a member being unloaded prior to the destructor of `Foo` being called, as I'm led to believe the order in which these happen is not defined. Could that be the problem?

It's easy enough to work around it, but I haven't come across this behaviour before and am trying to understand it.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Also, did you built the library yourself? If you do, perhaps it would be fine to recompile the library [with address sanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-code-generation) *(available on both of GCC and Clang)*.

Comment: If by conclusion of the program you mean program termination, it could be that the shared library gets unloaded prior to the global objects getting destroyed, hence the call to Bar Destructor will be a call to a pure virtual function.

Comment: Hi-Angel - this isn't a library I built myself, so it would be difficult for me to use the address sanitizer. Thank you for the suggestion though, I wasn't aware of that prior to your comment.

MicahlCMS - That is what I meant. My guess was exactly what you describe, but I was unsure if that was a possibility (as I said, as far as I could tell there is no prescription for the timing of global object destruction in a C++ program).